# Using C++ how can I stop a sleep() thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm creating a code which puts an application to sleep for 1000 MS, I want the sleep() thread to be done when I left click the mouse button. I got that working for now but I want to be able to make the sleep thread happen only once and then after the key is being pressed it stops the sleep(). 
It would only return the sleep thread once I stop clicking and then click again.

Comment: You generally can't do that. You could sleep for a shorter duration in a loop however. Maybe 250 ms and break out of that loop. However this would depend on what API you were using. Standard `c++` does not have the concept of a mouse. You need to tag what api or framework you are using for more accurate advice.

Comment: Commanding a thread to sleep is the most misused because miss understood thing in timing. What you are callback like handlers for timers and click events. Like on boost::asio and Qt.

Comment: Also post your code.

Comment: If your app handles mouse clicks, then it probably is based on a GUI framework. In that case, don't "put the app to sleep for one second." Start a one second timer, and put the app into a different, "sleep-like," state--a state in which it presents the _appearance_ of "being asleep" (whatever that means) to the user; but during which time it still can respond to events. Then, write handlers that put the app back into the "normal state" when the timer fires or, when the user clicks the mouse, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can end a sleep early by waiting on a condition variable and then signalling that condition variable when the mouse button is clicked.

Here is some proof-of-concept code which should show you how to do it:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::chrono::time_point <std::chrono::steady_clock> start_time;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;

void demo_thread ()
{
    std::cout << "demo thread waiting...\n";
    std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lk (cv_m);
    cv.wait_for (lk, 1000ms);
    auto delta_t = std::chrono::steady_clock::now () - start_time;
    std::cout << "demo thread terminating, delta_t = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (delta_t).count() << "ms\n";
}

int main ()
{
    start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now ();
    auto t = std::thread (demo_thread);
    std::cout << "main thread waiting...\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (200ms);

    std::cout << "signal condition variable...\n";
    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lk (cv_m);
        cv.notify_one ();
    }
    t.join ();
    std::cout << "main thread terminating\n";
}
```

Output:

```
main thread waiting...
demo thread waiting...
signal condition variable...
demo thread terminating, delta_t = 200ms
main thread terminating
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4gX2E4L7GfUkJCF8)